# How to set font Bold to a particular row in table widget

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

i want to set my font as bold in particular row column position of my tablewidget.
I did like this but getting break.

```
QFont font("Helvetica", 12, QFont::Bold);
overviewTable->item(2,2)->setFont(font);
```

Please Help

Comment: What is overviewTable? Is it QTableWidget or QTableView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think everything is ok. Here what docs said:

```
void QTableWidgetItem::setFont ( const QFont & font )
```

Sets the font used to display the item's text to the given font.

Maybe your *overviewTable* const?

**ADDED:**

This variant works fine for my Qt 4.6:

```
tableWidget = new QTableWidget(12, 3, this);

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(
            (i+1)*(j+1)));
        tableWidget->setItem(i, j, newItem);
    }
}

QFont font;
font.setBold(true);

tableWidget->item(2, 2)->setFont(font);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting break because you didn't call `setItem()` to set an item for the cell (2, 2) before you use `overviewTable->item(2,2)`. As the Qt document says,

> QTableWidgetItem * QTableWidget::item(int row, int column) const
>
> Returns the item for the given row and column if one has been set;
>   otherwise returns 0.

That is, your `overviewTable->item(2,2)` probably returns 0, thus causes a `Segmentation fault` in the `setFont()` call.

So your means to setting font is completely right. You just need to call setItem() at first as mosg's answer suggests.

**ADDED:**

if your `overviewTable` is a `QTableWidget` created in Qt Designer, then in the Designer  a double-click on a cell (just to enter its editing mode, no need to actually enter anything) will have the effect of calling `setItem()` for that cell. Later in your code you can directly using the `item()` function without having to call `setItem()` first.